# Override [UIButton Appearance] for one button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiappearance

See subject. Is this possible? When I add a tint color with UIButton Appearance... it applies to all UIButtons, not just "System" buttons but even custom ones.

I just want to be able to set a couple of destructive buttons with red text while keeping a customizable tint color for everything else.

Comment: Simply set the tint color explicitly for those special buttons.

Comment: I did that and UIAppearance still overrides them.

Comment: You should show some relevant code. Show how (and when) you setup all of the buttons using `UIAppearance` and then show how (and when) you try to setup the specific buttons with their own colors.

Comment: I don't think code is necessary for this example. It's not complex. Set [UIButton appearance] tint color in app delegate to green, drop a button on a form and try to change the tint color of that button to red somehow, in storyboard or code or whatever, doesn't work. I think Nirav's answer might be the only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`UIAppearance appearanceWhenContainedIn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906-CH1-SW2).

This one provides way to customize appearance whenever your control is contained within specific view, such as UIToolbar or UINavigationBar. You may check up your own parent view class which contains your custom UIButton.